# Pasar la clave publica de un certificado a Base64 con python

Tags: python, base64, certificado-ssl

necesito pasar el contenido de un certificado a base64 pero me esta dando problemas:

```
def depurar_public_key(archivo):
    archivo_cert = open(archivo).read()
    archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")
    archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")
    archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("\n", "")
    archivo_cert = archivo_cert.encode('utf-8', 'strict')
    archivo_cert = str(base64.b64encode(archivo_cert))
    archivo_cert = archivo_cert[2:-1]
    return archivo_cert
```

Certificado publico:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

El resultado que obtengo no es correcto(es mas largo de lo normal)

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: adjunto el archivo del certificado:

Answer (score 1):

No sé qué pretendes exactamente con el código, pero lo que tienes en el certificado, entre las líneas `----` que marcan su comienzo y fin **ya está en base64**.

¿Quizás lo que quieres es decodificarlo?

Más detalles:

- `archivo_cert = archivo_cert.encode('utf-8', 'strict')` No tiene sentido que uses utf-8 como encoding, pues el contenido, al ser base64, está limitado a 64 caracteres ASCII (de ahí el nombre base64). Puedes usar `.encode("ascii")`, aunque lee el tercer punto.
- No necesitas hacer `str()` sobre lo que te devuelve `base64.b64encode(archivo_cert)`, pues ya devuelve un string, aunque lee el siguiente punto.
- En realidad los dos puntos anteriores son irrelevantes, porque en realidad no querías usar `.b64encode()` sino (supongo) `b64decode()`.

Por tanto:

```
archivo_cert = txt
archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")
archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")
archivo_cert = archivo_cert.replace("\n", "")
archivo_cert = base64.b64decode(archivo_cert)
```

y esto te genera una cadena de bytes en `archivo_cert` de longitud 957 (no sé si es la que esperas, tampoco entiendo por qué retornas un subconjunto en el que quitas los dos primeros caracteres y el último).

Si vuelves a codificar esta secuencia en base64 usando `base64.b64encode(archivo_cert)` vuelves a obtener una cadena de caracteres `"MIID..."` que coincide con la que tenías en el certificado ASCII. Si lo que querías era esa representación (que ya era base64) naturalmente puedes ahorrarte todas estas conversiones y retornar directamente lo que te queda tras eliminar cabeceras y retornos de carro.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices y lo he aplicado pero me sigue dando el mismo fallo, Es una aplicación que conecta con una API y me da este error: {"tppMessages":[{"category":"ERROR","code":"CERTIFICATE_INVALID","text":"[APIGW002] The contents of the signature/corporate seal certificate are not matching PSD2 general PSD2 or attribute requirements: not in Base64"}]}

Comment: Creo que el problema esta en el modulo de http.client de Python, le puse el set_debuglevel(1) al objeto de la conexión y estoy viendo que añade retornos de carro(\r) y nuevas linias(\n) al enviar el header, quizá sea por eso que me dice que no esta en base64 otra cosa no se me ocurre :S